# Rails 3 - find condition on a many to many through association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-3.1

I have three models: User, Task and Assignation. 
User has many tasks through assignation.
Tasks has many users through assignation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignations
  has_many :tasks, :through => :assignations 
  ...

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignations
  has_many :users, :through => :assignations
```

I have a partial which shows all the tasks of the selected user.
How can I make the condition efficiently so I can get the collection of tasks?

i.e.

```
user_id = params[:user_id]
@tasks = Task.find(:all, :conditions=> .....)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@tasks = User.find(params[:user_id]).tasks
```

should work fine.

Comment: Won't this return repeated values?